# Using Geotiff on Leafletjs - Get Value on Map Click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet, geotiff

I can't get any value when I click on my map.
I just want to get  the value of the pixel when map in onClick.
I tried using d3 and I make it to work, but using GeoRasterLayer load much faster on zoom that's why I am trying to make this work.

```
      var map = L.map('map').setView([12.46876, 121.915039], 6);

      var layer = "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
      L.tileLayer(layer, {
        attribution: "OSM & Carto",
        subdomains: "abcd",
        maxZoom: 19
      }).addTo(map);

      // tif file
      var url_to_geotiff_file = "../src/rr.gpm1hr.20221026.233000.tif";

      fetch(url_to_geotiff_file)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
          parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {
            const min = georaster.mins[0];
            const max = georaster.maxs[0];
            const range = georaster.ranges[0];

            var scale = chroma.scale(['#FFFFCC' ,'#C7E9B4' ,'#7FCDBB' ,'#41B6C4' ,'#1D91C0' ,'#225EA8' ,'#0C2C84']);

            var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                georaster: georaster,
                opacity: 0.7,
                pixelValuesToColorFn: function(pixelValues) {
                  var pixelValue = pixelValues[0];

                  if (pixelValue === 0) return null;

                  var scaledPixelValue = (pixelValue - min) / range;

                  var color = scale(scaledPixelValue).hex();

                  return color;
                },
                resolution: 256
            }).addTo(map);

            map.on('click', function (e) {
                if(e.pixelValue !== null){
                    let v = e.pixelValue;
                    let html = (`<span class="popupText">Value: ${v}</span>`);
                    let popup = L.popup()
                        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                        .setContent(html)
                        .openOn(map);
                }
            });
          });
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have been looking for the answer to this for a long time and i found it in here:  https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster-layer-for-leaflet/issues/104

maybe it is late but it may help someone in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).